# convert md5 hash output into integer in Teradata

Tags: sql, hashcode, teradatasql

is it possible to convert `uuid` column value to int value using `MD5` or other any other hashing function in  `Teradata`.

```
select hash_md5("HelloWorld") ==> 68E109F0F40CA72A15E05CC22786F8E6
```

Expecting :

```
select hash_md5("HelloWorld") ==> int32
```

Comment: UDF hash_md5 returns a 128-bit value as a hex character string, which you may be able to convert to BYTE(16) but that doesn't fit in a 32-bit (4-byte) INT. The native HASHROW function returns a BYTE(4).